# How to have a texture-changing SpriteKit node?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift5, gamekit

I'm trying to figure out how to make a SpriteKit node have a randomised texture and for it to travel across the screen (Also to save the bag data but I'll add that later)

I'm struggling on the texture bit. I've set up a randomiser and for it to call the texture. But setting it to the node I'm unsure

Here's the code I've got so far

```
func createBag() {
    let randomBagSelect = Int.random(in: 0..<4)
    
    if var bagNode = self.bagNode {
    
        if randomBagSelect == 0 {
            bagNode = (SKTexture(imageNamed: "Suitcase 1"))
        }
        
        if randomBagSelect == 1 {
            bagNode = (SKTexture(imageNamed: "Suitcase 2"))
        }
        
        if randomBagSelect == 2 {
            bagNode = (SKTexture(imageNamed: "Suitcase 3"))
        }
        
        if randomBagSelect == 3 {
            bagNode = (SKTexture(imageNamed: "Suitcase 4"))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't that just the matter of having an `SKSpriteNode` object as a variable?

Comment: It doesn't like it when i try and set it to SKSpriteNode as in the if statements I'm setting it as SKTexure

Answer (score 0):

If bagNode is the SKSpriteNode object, then setting its texture is done like this:

```
bagNode.texture = (SKTexture(imageNamed: "Suitcase 1"))
```

Comment: I seem to be unable to do that. I have added the .texture to bagNode (It's set as SKSpriteNode in the sks file) and I get the error "Value of type 'SKTexture' ha sno member 'texture' "

Comment: So bagNode is currently a texture not an SKSpriteNode. For the GameScene file to refer to your sks file, you typically have something like this. In the top of your file,  var bagNode: SKSpriteNode?, and in the didMove section
bagNode = childNode(withName: "bagnode") as? SKSpriteNode. The withName being whatever you called it in your sks file.